# "Ask Question" Window rework

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, editor

While it's an "ok to use" tool for experienced SO users, who know its quirks and have experience with submitting questions, I think it has some problems that make it hard for new users to submit good and coherent questions. And some quirks that even annoy mediocre to experienced users who haven't visited the site in some time.

One problem is that, by default, the question is cut into a short strip. While this may be helpful in some contexts, an option to view the full question without having to scroll to the preview would be helpful.

On the other hand the page has a lot of free space on wider monitors; while I see the need to support smaller screens and keep the Site coherent for users across different platforms having the option would be great.

Another problem is the code implementation. By default code is indicated by four spaces in front of a new line, why not use a tag instead? This is one of the most common new user mistakes and annoyances even for experienced users. There are extra questions and meta questions on how to use it. Which, at least for me, is an indication of horrible UI. I don't see an advantage of those four spaces and `` compared to a simple opening and closing tag for code.

Another inconvenience is that we have a different view for the text and the preview of the text. A more modern approach, I think, would be to inline the preview and convert the representation to text when the element is clicked.

Looking at how SO is a multi-million user site of programmers, I think we can change that. Either the company SO could rework the window or the community could contribute an open source solution.

I know that Web development across different browsers and versions is/was a pain in the arse. But, seeing as modern browsers are more compatible with each other and you could still display the old version on old browsers, I simply don't see the downside of such a rework.

Comment: `By default code is indicated by 4 spaces in front of a new line, why not use a tag instead?` you mean like this: `<code></code>`?

Comment: Or [code][/code]

Comment: `<code></code>` already exists.

Comment: Most of the choices in Stack Overflow's UI aren't because the technology they use is old; they're conscious decisions. Having worked with, and implemented, dozens of different WYSIWYG browser editors, and having cursed them all at some point in time for their flakiness, I'd choose Stack Overflow's awesome Markdown interface over any of them any time. A separate input/preview is kind of inherent to the approach, although if you can point to an implementation that does it better, fire away

Comment: Interesting, I never new that and have seen a lot of senior devs complain about code formatting on SO.

Comment: Well, you *have* to click the "advanced help" link to be told about `<code></code>` - perhaps that could be moved into the help dialog itself. It's really not impossible to find either way, though. Personally, I can't say I've ever had any problems with code formatting on SO. I find it very easy to defend them on most UI issues - Stack Overflow's minimalistic UI is one of the most pleasant I've ever used. I work with web apps every day and most of them make me long for it

Comment: I don't think I ever clicked that little question mark in the 3-4 years I'm a member of SO. Or I simply can't remember because I did it twice and then never again.

Comment: I've never clicked it in 7 years until just now - but if you are having problems with using the editor, its hardly seems asking too much to click it.

Comment: Some of this is reasonable, some of it isn't. Arguably the horizontal space should be better used so that the preview is more visible. But Markdown (which is already open source, BTW) is *significantly* easier to use than any alternative markup system, which is why it was chosen. And WYSIWYG editors suck, so that's an absolute nonstarter. I have seen *absolutely* no evidence that experienced users have trouble getting their code formatted. The only people that struggle with this are new users who don't bother to read any of the help that we provide. A more complicated editor surely won't help.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem mostly shows up when an eclipse dev tries to answer a question with an answer that isn't related to work. Or maybe gives in to the temptation of writing a short answer for an "easy" question and then needs to format or just wants to add/remove an if quickly. It's questionable if those quick answer would be helpful though and how much community-(work-)force one would gain in SO by "fixing" that.

Comment: This is a list of *preferences*. None of them is *better* than the current SO editor because all of them are subjective. (Also, you can already resize the editor window.)

Answer (score 19):

> I think [the editor] has some problems that make it hard for new users to submit good and coherent questions.

Oh, it was the editor all along!

Wait, no, it wasn't, it's the users themselves. If you can't form full sentences, if you can't create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifyable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you don't even bother double-checking what your wall of text looks like, then no editor whatsoever is going to save you. "You" being a question asker of course, not particularly you the OP.

> have seen a lot of senior devs complain about code formatting on SO

That's because you shouldn't be editing or formatting code in the Stack Overflow editor in the first place.

You create a MCVE offline, then select the code, (shift-)tab it until the indentation is one tab or four spaces, then copy-paste it into the editor. Done.

Yes, Markdown is the umpteenth attempt to create a markup language that every person should be able to understand, and it has *some* learning curve, but it's way, way better than all its predecessors (BBCode, HTML-subsets, and all variants I forgot about).

And don't get me started on WYSI(NQ)WYG.

Comment: `Oh, it was the editor all along!` LOL

Comment: For eclipse users it's a pain in the arse to create a new snippet, because you have to change workspace or put some code you have to remove temporarily in your local repository. Many seniors at my last company dreaded the latter solutions. When you change workspace you don't have the enviroment to build the MCVE anymore. So I writing it in SO seems like the lesser evil I think. Though it's of course an Eclipse problem.

Comment: `And don't get me started on WYSI(NQ)WYG.` Yeah, WYSIWYG in the browser is a complete catastrophe and hasn't evolved one iota since when all this started, with IE4's editable content area thingy IIRC. Oh, you clicked the "bold" button on a "h1" element and made it blue? It's up to the gods what kind of markup that results in. There's a lot of possible combinations for the `<span>`, `<strong>`, and `<h1>` involved.  Perhaps you'll even get a `<p>` or two. And when editing that concoction... something completely new emerges. Have fun writing a style sheet for that!

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I haven't touched Eclipse in a while. Is a "Workspace" a collection of projects rooted from a certain directory on disk, just as Visual Studio's "Solution"? Then creating a new workspace to create a [mcve] should be trivial. If not, that's the editor's or programmer's problem. By typing new code in the editor and assuming it actually compiles and reproduces the issue, you're potentially asking an off-topic question (no-repro).

Comment: `you shouldn't be editing or formatting code in the Stack Overflow editor in the first place.` Yeah, but you also have to know about the order of copy any pasting first. And then remember it if you use SO seldom, even for answers this can be a pain sometimes.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful _"if you want to change the variable names for the MCVE"_ - again, the MCVE should exist in your IDE even before you click the Ask a Question button.

Comment: Your comments are incoherent, if I need to mask my business logic with generic variable names to not reveal my identity or that of a customer, I create an MCVE and then change the variable names, when I do that in my-editor I either have to temporarily refactor the Code or change them after it's done. If I then want to iterate on it because of a comment, I would have to change it back and forth. Often the context of the application is important for bugs, but cannot be posted. Especially for ex in android questions. An 100% self containted MCVE is something I have  only seen in simple contexts.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful _"Your comments are incoherent"_ - thanks, why? _"Often the context of the application is important for bugs"_ - and I find that rarely to be the case. It's the M of Minimal. Anyway, if you must copy-paste code to rename variables or whatever (again, this should never have to be the case), then simply copy-paste it into a decent editor (Notepad++ for example) to do a search & replace and fix the indentation. I really don't consider this to be the job of Stack Exchange's editor window.

Comment: You say that a MCVE should happen in the same context or atleast in a verifiable context, which might require renaming variables to mask stuff afterwords like I mentioned. You already answered that though. (Max comment length can sometimes be a pain.). Btw. thanks for the discussion. It was just a random thought that popped up and seeing other people opinions even on technical thinks is also satisfying.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful if you have to rename things *after* creating the MCVE, it's not really a MCVE. If there is context you're not showing that alters the behaviour, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: That depends on the language, platform and version-dependency. In pure java and modern c++ I agree. But in Android you often have context dependant questions, but those contexts are clear to anyone who spend more than 1 day with android. And you can aswell explain the context afterwards in non-code form.

Comment: So the editor is why we have so many terrible Android questions? Obviously I don't get it. I type 99% of my answers directly into the Stack Overflow editor, code and all. The only thing I miss is having my tab key insert spaces. I used to have an extension that did that, but then the Chrome team decided that I was too stupid to be allowed to use extensions and permanently disabled them. Anyway, I don't understand how platform or language would have anything to do with it. If you can't code except in an IDE, you can copy-paste; the editor supports that. If you can code in a text editor, well..

Comment: I think it's a contributing factor for beginners. Like I said, scrolling down and then up again to see the whole question isn't really practical if you need to make a lot of changes. This can be hindering for people which somewhat struggle with language in general, especially with the SO format, which isn't a normal forum (cut out your emotions). And then especially for people with bad english. Looking at it once wasn't cutting it for me, I need to see the whole thing while typing. And scrolling up and down wasn't really an option, cause I would need to scroll like a maniac.

Comment: I disagree if you take your time and read what you are doing this is not a problem, I struggle English myself but that means you have to be more careful in what you are saying if it isn't clear, scrolling up and down won't affect reading your own question carefully.  You shouldn't need to "scroll like a maniac".

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: Markdown, *by design*, is intended to be perfectly readable as plain-text. So you should just be able to scroll up/down in your text box to see what you're typing.

Comment: *"you have to change workspace or put some code you have to remove temporarily in your local repository"*. I'm sorry to break the news here, but those "senior" developers have no idea how to use their IDE. As for the markdown editor, it's supposed to be a *text editor* and while it would be nice if it could support proper markdown like "```[language]" the suggestion to write the code in an actual IDE and paste it solves any problems you might have with the formatting.